# Trying to achieve a smooth transition in sticky menus

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, sticky

Hi,

I have a logo that becomes fixed on top as soon as the user starts scrolling down and the logo goes up off the screen. The logo also becomes smaller.

This is my code:

```js
//<![CDATA[
    $(function(){
            // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
            var stickyHeaderTop = $('#logo').offset().top + 160;
     
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                            $('#logo').addClass('fixed');
                    } else {
                            $('#logo').removeClass('fixed');
                    }
            });
      });//]]>
```

```css
    #logo {
        height: 145px;
        margin: 10px 0 0;
        transition:all 1s ease 0s;
        top: -160px;
        color:black;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
    .fixed {
        height: 55px !important;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0!important;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    body {min-height:1000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">SOME LOGO HERE</div>
```

everything fine as you scroll down because the animation is smooth. However, as you scroll back up the transition is choppy because the element just disappears and reappears instead of gradually going back to its original place.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix width of Fixed class.update and add following to .fixed

```js
//<![CDATA[
    $(function(){
            // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
            var stickyHeaderTop = $('#logo').offset().top + 160;
     
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                            $('#logo').addClass('fixed');
                    } else {
                            $('#logo').removeClass('fixed');
                    }
            });
      });//]]>
```

```css
#logo {
        height: 145px;
        margin: 10px 0 0;
        transition:all 1s ease 0s;
        top: -160px;
        color:black;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
    .fixed {
        height: 55px !important;
        width: 100%;
        width: -moz-available;          /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
        width: -webkit-fill-available; 
        position: fixed;
        top: 0!important;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    body {min-height:1000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">SOME LOGO HERE</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesnt change anything. The logo still disappears and just reappears in place as you scroll back up.

Comment: what you want a smooth transition ?

Comment: Yes, I need a smooth transition for when the logo goes back to its original place as you scroll back up.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Don't** use id selectors (`#`) is CSS. It tends to create specificity problem that you already ran into and forced you to use `!important` (which you should *almost* never use) in your `.fixed` selector. Read more about it [here](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/) or [here](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/). Yes, there are valid exceptions, but you need to apply those only once you know exactly what and why you're doing there.
2. You cannot animate the `position` property, so you need to find a solution where `position: fixed;` does not change. The switching to position fixed probably causes the unsmooth behaviour.
3. Use this corrected snippet's code to work your way to the solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
  var stickyHeaderTop = $('#logo').offset().top + 160;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
      $('#logo').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $('#logo').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.logo {
  height: 145px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  top: -160px;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.logo.fixed {
  height: 55px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
body {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo" class="logo">SOME LOGO HERE</div>
```

Comment: An obeservation, the logo must appear from the beginning but bigger. Then as the user scrolls down it comes down and gets smaller.

Comment: I'm not going to solve it for your, I just explained which problems your code and approach has. You'll have to figure it out on your own now.

Comment: Sorry but then your answer is not an answer because is of no help at all.

Comment: It might not be a ready-to-go solution, but it should definitely help you with bad conceptions you probably weren't aware of. Also, since it contains an improved version of your code to start with, it was not possible to put this as a comment.

Comment: I appreciate your intention but I was already aware that position is not animatable. Thats why I am requesting an alternative to deal with that. Without that Im stuck in the same step.